# Mysql How to prevent record from change in update?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have one form to create and edit a simple blog .
but I want to prevent change on mysql record when update Ex. DateCreated .
is there anyway to perform this in php and mysql ?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `DateCreated` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Use a pre-update trigger.

Comment: I know this is going to sound silly but ! If you dont want to change a row once it is created, why do you have an EDIT form

Comment: My guess is he/she wants to update all other columns but never the `DateCreated` column, that is only set during insert.

Comment: You could simply use `set DateCreated = DateCreated` in all of your update statements … or you disable the auto-update of date field “feature”, and explicitly specify it as NOW() during the initial INSERT …

Comment: @TheImpaler Ahh, that makes more sense. In that case make the `dateCreated` into `\`DateCreated\` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` And just done change that value in the Edit form

Comment: Simple don't add the record you don't want to be updated on your `update statement`

Comment: what about IS NULL Values ?